# Page_Load event only firing once

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a webapp I've been working on and it has several tabs on it.
The first tab has all the code necessary to repopulate a gridview after xx seconds using a timer_tick event.  This tab works great.  No issues.
I have virtually the same code on tab #2 with a gridview, timer and all the other necessary objects to repopulate this gridview after yy amount of seconds.  Thing is, the timer_tick event of that page is only firing once.
I've got a breakpoint set one line below **"protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)"**.  It gets hit once and that's it. During the initial load procedure. 
Here's what I've tried to remedy the problem:

1. Encapsulated the method (it's called "Refresh()") in a **if(!isPostback)** logic.  This did not work.
2. Confirmed in the .aspx file that in the page header there is **"AutoEventWireup="true" "** code.
3. Confirmed there is no code in the document to set the **timer.enabled = "false"**
4. Encapsulated the method in a **"if (!Page.IsPostback)"** logic.

None of these appear to help.
I'm trying to get the "Refresh()" event to fire every, let's say 60 seconds.  But the only way to get it to start working is to actually click on any of the objects (buttons) on that particular tab.  THEN everything starts working as I would like.
Is there something I missing, if so, what?
Please let me know if you have any questions.

UPDATE--  Requested code: (From databaseholds.aspx.cs file.  Also, I

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {    
        Refresh();          
    }
```

It hits that breakpoint one time, on load, and that's it, unless I click on any object on the page.

[image: It hits that breakpoint one time, on load, and that's it.]

And yes, the timer is set within an update panel but it is not using the same update panel as the first tab. 
The first one (working) is called "uppBackupRestore" and the second one (not working) is called "uppDatabaseHolds".

Let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Is your control wrapped inside an `UpdatePanel`? If so, is it the same UpdatePanel the first tab (the one that works) is using?

Comment: Shared and updated my original message.